# Как использовать второй поток в Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет. Мне нужно сделать игру с помощью потоков на Tkinter. Первый поток - это музыка, второй - игра. Я не знаю как использовать второй поток в Tk. Вот мой код:
lib:

```
from threading import Thread

from os import system

from random import randint


class MusicThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self) -> None:
        system("music.mp3")


class Game(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__number = int(input('Введите число'))
        self.__random_number = randint(0, 10)

    def run(self):
        if self.__number == self.__random_number:
            print('Угадал')
        else:
            print(f'Неправильно - {self.__random_number}')
```

form:

```
from tkinter import *

from lib.lib import *


from tkinter import *
from lib.lib import *


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = Tk()
        self.__button = Button(self.__root)
        self.__entry = Entry(self.__root)
        self.__thread2 = Game()
        self.__thread1 = MusicThread()
        self.__thread1.daemon = True
        self.__thread2.daemon = False

    def config(self):
        self.__root.title("Угадай число")
        self.__root.geometry("400x300+100+100")
        self.__root.resizable(False, False)
        self.__root.config(bg="black")
        self.__button.config(text="Click", font="Arial 11")
        self.__entry.config(text=0)

    def layout(self):
        self.__entry.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1, anchor=CENTER)
        self.__button.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.1, anchor=CENTER)

    def bindings(self):
        self.__button.bind('<Button>', self.slot1)

    def slot1(self):
        self.__thread1.start()

    def show(self):
        self.config()
        self.bindings()
        self.layout()
        self.__root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Игру не выносите в отдельный поток. Просто напишите игру на tkinter без потоков, а потом добавьте музыку в отдельном потоке.

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama как считать число что я записал в Entry? Его же нужно сравнить с рандомным числом

Comment: Это легко гуглится, но к счастью я и так это помню: `entry.get()`

Answer (score -1):

Исходный код

```
from threading import Thread

from os import system

from random import randint


class MusicThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self) -> None:
        system("music.mp3")


class Game(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__number = int(input('Введите число'))
        self.__random_number = randint(0, 10)

    def run(self):
        if self.__number == self.__random_number:
            print('Угадал')
        else:
            print(f'Неправильно - {self.__random_number}')
```

а вот то что должно работать

```
from os import system
from threading import Thread
from random import randint


class MusicThread():
    def run():
        system("music.mp3")


class Game():
      

    def run():
        __number = int(input('Введите число'))
        __random_number = randint(0, 10)
        if __number == __random_number:
            print('Угадал')
        else:
            print(f'Неправильно - {__random_number}')
if __name__ == '__main__':

    Thread(target=Game.run).start()
    Thread(target=MusicThread.run).start()
```